# Authorize button missing in Google App Engine swagger.json

Tags: google-app-engine, flask-restplus

I have a flask restplus api with swagger documentation generated.

When I run the application locally, I am able to see the Authorize button in the swagger UI

Localhost has Authorize button
[image]

But when I deploy the same application on Google App Engine, the authorize button goes missing.

No Authorize button in the Google App Engine deployment.
[image]

I am unsure why the authorize button is missing in the Google App Engine deployment.

Comment: I was using different versions of flask-restpplus on localhost and Google app engine. After bumping  up the app engine deployment to use the latest version of flask restplus, I am able to see the authorize button.

Answer (score 1):

I was using different versions of flask-restpplus on localhost and Google app engine. After bumping up the app engine deployment to use the latest version of flask restplus, I am able to see the authorize button