# Fastapi - openapi authorize button goes away

Tags: swagger, openapi, fastapi, openapi-generator

I have created a python app using fastapi and therefore I have generated an openapi document `http://localhost:8084/docs`. I am building the app locally using docker-compose. In the beginning I was able to see the `authorize` button but now when I load the page `http://localhost:8084/docs` it just appears for a blink of an eye and then disappears. This is quite strange for me as it was working fine.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033390/authorize-button-missing-in-google-app-engine-swagger-json) could be a possible duplicate but it shows that locally it works fine and there was a problem when it was deployed to Google App Engine. In my case, it was working fine locally and after deployment as well but now I cna't see that `authorize` button anywhere. Any ideas or experiences with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in Swagger UI `3.30.1`. You might want to upgrade your fastapi to the latest version if possible. The latest version, `0.60.1`, was just released yesterday. Fastapi has pinned the version for swagger ui to `3.30.0`.

You can get more information from [this issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1762)